# STL priority_queue parameters

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

When creating a STL priority_queue, the third argument (the one that decides how to compare elements in the queue to decide which is largest)must be a class in which the function operator is defined.  It would be much more convenient if a lambda expression could be supplied.  Why is that not allowed?  A lambda expression should be considered to be compile time constant if it is not capturing any variables, right?

```
struct compare{
  bool operator()(int p, int q){return p > q;}
};

priority_queue< int, vector<int>, compare> intpq;

priority_queue< int, vector<int>,
                [](int p, int q){return p > q;}
 > intpq2;
```

The second definition, i.e. of intpq2, gives an error: template argument 3 is invalid.  Is there a fundamental problem in accepting the second definition, or is it just that the designers of priority_queue chose not to allow it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `std::priority_queue` is a type. A lambda expression is not a type, but rather, an expression (you can think of it as an instance or object of something). On top of that, lambdas do not have an type that can be known *a priori*, but stateless lambdas do convert to pointer to function .

There are some work-arounds you can use in order to instantiate priority_queues with lambdas:

- Make the 3rd parameter a pointer to function and pass a stateless lambda to the constructor. You can also pass plain function pointers. For example,
- Make the 3rd parameter an `std::function<bool(int, int)>` and pass any kind of lambda that matches the correct signature to the constructor. You can pass anything that can be used to construct an `std::function<bool(int)>`.

For example,

```
// no capture. Pointer to function is OK
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, bool (*)(int, int)>
    q2([](int a, int b){return a < b;});
```

or

```
// capture. Can't use pointer to function.
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int, int)>>
    q2([some_var](int a, int b){return a < b;});
```

Comment: Well, lambdas, like all expressions, have a type. It's just an unspeakable one.

Comment: @T.C. Rephrased (and added examples.)

Comment: The answer is helpful.  However, it does not answer my question: is there a fundamental problem in defining priority_queue template class so that the comparison function could be accepted as a function rather than as a class.  I guess for that the template parameter would have to be a function type, with arguments of type = the type of the object stored in the priority_queue.  This is perhaps not allowed -- at least it did not work in an example I tried compiling.  In any case, thanks.

Comment: @Ekalavya Obviously not. My first example accepts a function. The class limitation does not exist.

Comment: It accepts a function in the constructor -- but not as a template argument.

Comment: @Ekalavya It accepts the type of a function as template parameter. It cannot accept an instance of a function as one. Just like it can't accept an instance of a functor as a template parameter.

Comment: When you say "cannot accept an instance of a function", do you mean specifically priority_queue cannot (which I agree with), or do you mean that priority_queue cannot be rewritten to accept an instance of a function as a template argument?

Comment: @Ekalavya I don't think it can be re-written without breaking backwards compatibility. Even if it could, it isn't going to happen so the question is moot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74251/discussion-between-ekalavya-and-juanchopanza).

Comment: @Ekalavya Template non-type arguments are only allowed to be certain specific types because they need to be mangled. And though there are talks about extending the range of allowed types, `std::function` with its complex type-erasure machinery, which often requires dynamic allocation, is almost certainly never going to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The third template parameter of `priority_queue` is a type. Lambda expressions are, well, *expressions*, not types. An expression has a type. Each lambda expression has a distinct, "unspeakable", type. Pretty much the only way you can refer to it is via `auto` and `decltype`:

```
auto cmp = [](int a, int b){return a < b;};
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q1(cmp);
```

Which is OK if you are just using `q1` locally. If you need to pass it around, it can be rather difficult for the users of your function to spell the `priority_queue`'s type, and you may need to resort to one of the ways shown in @juanchopanza's answer.